# Angular 11 - mat-grid-list not recognised in one component but working in several others

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, angular-module

I have added a new component to my large Angular project. I use the  component to layout the page. What is weird is that the new component generates an error. I have dealed with these kinds of problems of missing AngularMaterial design, and I can confirm everything is present in the app.module.ts:

```
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatGridListModule
```

My component header looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-workflow-triggers-manager',
  template: '<div><mat-grid-list></mat-grid-list></div>',
  // templateUrl: './workflow-triggers-manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workflow-triggers-manager.component.css', '../../../codehighlight.css']
})
export class WorkflowTriggersManagerComponent implements OnInit {
[SNIP]
}
```

The error:

```
Error: src/app/components/scenariomanagement/workflow-triggers-manager/workflow-triggers-manager.component.ts:76:19 - error NG8001: 'mat-grid-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-grid-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-grid-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

76   template: '<div><mat-grid-list></mat-grid-list></div>',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My project at the moment is quite large, could this be a cause? Because after adding a new (other) component was added this problem arose.

What I tried is just commenting out the whole template in the given file and then all works perfectly (except for this component of course).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update 1**: removed the new other component and that didn't solve the problem.

**Update 2**: shared the complete app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule, HammerModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CrisisActionListComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/crisis-action-list/crisis-action-list.component';
import {WorkInProgressListComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/work-in-progress-list/work-in-progress-list.component';
import {IndicatorListComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/indicator-list/indicator-list.component';
import {CrisisDocumentListComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/crisis-document-list/crisis-document-list.component';
import {MessageListComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/message-list/message-list.component';
import {RealTimeIndicatorComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/real-time-indicator/real-time-indicator.component';
import {GameTimeIndicatorComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/game-time-indicator/game-time-indicator.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {WorkInProgressItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/work-in-progress-item/work-in-progress-item.component';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {CrisisActionComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/crisis-action/crisis-action.component';
import {IndicatorItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/indicator-item/indicator-item.component';
import {MessageItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/message-item/message-item.component';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {CrisisDocumentComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/crisis-document/crisis-document.component';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {GaugeChartModule} from 'angular-gauge-chart';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {ProblemListComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/problemlist-impact/problem-list.component';
import {ProblemItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/problem-item/problem-item.component';
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
import localeNL from '@angular/common/locales/nl';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {DashboardComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {ContentViewerComponent} from './components/shared/content-viewer/content-viewer.component';
import {LoginPageComponent} from './security/login-page/login-page.component';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {httpInterceptorProviders} from './interceptors';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {LandingpageComponent} from './components/startup/landingpage/landingpage.component';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {ScenarioManagementComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/scenario-management/scenario-management.component';
import {ScenarioSubitemComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/scenario-parts/scenario-subitem.component';
import {DialogEditBerichtItemComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-bericht/dialog-edit-bericht-item.component';
import {FormErrorAlertComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/form-error-alert/form-error-alert.component';
import {WorkflowManagementComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/workflow-management/workflow-management.component';
import {TaskManagerComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/task-manager/task-manager.component';
import {TaskDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/task-details/task-details.component';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {ScenarioTimelineComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/scenario-timeline/scenario-timeline.component';
import {WorkflowDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/workflow-details/workflow-details.component';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {DialogEditWorkflowComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-workflow/dialog-edit-workflow.component';
import {TaskDetailsListComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/task-details-list/task-details-list.component';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {ScenarioDetailsComponent} from './components/shared/scenario-details/scenario-details.component';
import {DialogEditTaskComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-task/dialog-edit-task.component';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {TaskStatusPipe} from './pipes/task-status.pipe';
import {DialogEditActionComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-action/dialog-edit-action.component';
import {OrderByPipe} from './pipes/order-by.pipe';
import {DialogEditIndicatorComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-indicator/dialog-edit-indicator.component';
import {DialogEditGameComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-game/dialog-edit-game.component';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatMomentDateModule} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {DialogEditGameParticipantsComponent} from './components/managegames/dialog-edit-game-participants/dialog-edit-game-participants.component';
import {DialogEditActionRequiredDocumentsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-action-required-documents/dialog-edit-action-required-documents.component';
import {AfterActionDashboardComponent} from './components/AAR/after-action-dashboard/after-action-dashboard.component';
import {DialogEditContentComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-content/dialog-edit-content.component';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {DialogEditDocumentComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-document/dialog-edit-document.component';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {DialogEditProblemareaComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-problemarea/dialog-edit-problemarea.component';
import {DialogEditScenarioComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-scenario/dialog-edit-scenario.component';
import {ScenarioPartDocumentPipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-document.pipe';
import {ScenarioPartIndicatorPipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-indicator.pipe';
import {ScenarioPartActionPipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-action.pipe';
import {ScenarioPartWorkflowPipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-workflow.pipe';
import {ScenarioPartMessagePipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-message.pipe';
import {SubEditWorkflowInfoComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/sub-edit-workflow-info/sub-edit-workflow-info.component';
import {SubTriggerDescriptionComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/sub-trigger-description/sub-trigger-description.component';
import {ReportTimelineLogComponent} from './components/reports/report-timeline-log/report-timeline-log.component';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {ScenarioWorkflowDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-workflow-details/scenario-workflow-details.component';
import {TriStateCheckboxComponent} from './components/shared/tri-state-checkbox/tri-state-checkbox.component';
import {SimpleNotificationsModule} from 'angular2-notifications';
import {ScenarioPartStorylinePipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-storyline.pipe';
import {DialogEditStorylineComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-storyline/dialog-edit-storyline.component';
import {UserManagerComponent} from './components/Usermanagement/user-manager/user-manager.component';
import {UserDetailsComponent} from './components/Usermanagement/user-details/user-details.component';
import {DialogEditExecutorComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-executor/dialog-edit-executor.component';
import {AbsolutePipe} from './pipes/absolute.pipe';
import {VisualisationComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/visualisation/visualisation.component';
import {ScenarioStorylineEditorComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-storyline-editor/scenario-storyline-editor.component';
import {FilterStorylinePipe} from './pipes/filter-storyline.pipe';
import {UniqueStorylinesPipe} from './pipes/unique-storylines.pipe';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {FilterStorylineFromWorkflowsPipe} from './pipes/filter-storyline-from-workflows.pipe';
import {ScenarioDocumentDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-document-details/scenario-document-details.component';
import {ScenarioIndicatorDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-indicator-details/scenario-indicator-details.component';
import {ScenarioProblemareaDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-problemarea-details/scenario-problemarea-details.component';
import {ScenarioExecutorDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-executor-details/scenario-executor-details.component';
import {StorylineManagementComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/storyline-management/storyline-management.component';
import {FilterActionFromStorylinePipe} from './pipes/filter-action-from-storyline.pipe';
import {DragDropWorkflowsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/storyline-management/drag-drop-workflows/drag-drop-workflows.component';
import {DragDropActionsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/storyline-management/drag-drop-actions/drag-drop-actions.component';
import {FilterStorylineFromWorkflowExtPipe} from './pipes/filter-storyline-from-workflow-ext.pipe';
import {FilterActionsExtendedFromStorylinePipe} from './pipes/filter-actions-extended-from-storyline.pipe';
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {ServiceLocator} from './lib/service-locator';
import {DialogEditRoleComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-role/dialog-edit-role.component';
import {ScenarioPartRolePipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-role.pipe';
import {ReportScenarioRouteComponent} from './components/reports/report-scenario-route/report-scenario-route.component';
import {ReportScenarioPlayerReportComponent} from './components/reports/report-scenario-player-report/report-scenario-player-report.component';
import {ReportFullScenarioComponent} from './components/reports/report-full-scenario/report-full-scenario.component';
import {ReportDebriefingPreparationComponent} from './components/reports/report-debriefing-preparation/report-debriefing-preparation.component';
import {ScenarioActionDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-action-details/scenario-action-details.component';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {GenericInformationalPopupComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/dialogs/generic-informational-popup/generic-informational-popup.component';
import {ReportScenarioRolesComponent} from './components/reports/report-scenario-roles/report-scenario-roles.component';
import {CKEditorModule} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import {DialogGameInfoComponent} from './components/playgame/dialog-game-info/dialog-game-info.component';
import {SafeHtmlPipe} from './pipes/safe-html.pipe';
import {ReportGameplayContentComponent} from './components/reports/report-gameplay-content/report-gameplay-content.component';
import {ScenarioRoleDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-role-details/scenario-role-details.component';
import {DateTimeSelectorComponent} from './components/shared/date-time-selector/date-time-selector.component';
import {BulkCreateUsersComponent} from './components/Usermanagement/bulk-create-users/bulk-create-users.component';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {BulkEditUsersComponent} from './components/Usermanagement/bulk-edit-users/bulk-edit-users.component';
import {ScenarioPartProblemareaPipe} from './pipes/scenario-part-problemarea.pipe';
import {ScenarioMessageDetailsComponent} from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-message-details/scenario-message-details.component';
import {DialogActionItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/dialogs/dialog-action-item/dialog-action-item.component';
import {DialogMessageItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/dialogs/dialog-message-item/dialog-message-item.component';
import {GameSelectionComponent} from './components/playgame/game-selection/game-selection.component';
import {DialogShowContentComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/dialogs/dialog-show-content/dialog-show-content.component';
import {DialogInformationItemComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/dialogs/dialog-information-item/dialog-information-item.component';
import { FilterWorkflowFromSolutionCatPipe } from './pipes/filter-workflow-from-solution-cat.pipe';
import { FilterActionFromSolutionCatPipe } from './pipes/filter-action-from-solution-cat.pipe';
import { ScenarioSolutionCategoriesDetailsComponent } from './components/scenariomanagement/PartDetails/scenario-solution-categories-details/scenario-solution-categories-details.component';
import { DialogEditSolutionCategoryComponent } from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-edit-solution-category/dialog-edit-solution-category.component';
import { StakeholderReportComponent } from './components/reports/stakeholder-report/stakeholder-report.component';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {ReportUserExecutedActionsComponent} from './components/reports/report-user-executed-actions/report-user-executed-actions.component';
import { DialogSelectScenarioComponent } from './components/scenariomanagement/inputforms/dialog-select-scenario/dialog-select-scenario.component';
import { ReportPartIndicatorsComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-indicators/report-part-indicators.component';
import { ReportPartProblemareasComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-problemareas/report-part-problemareas.component';
import { ReportPartIndicatorDetailsComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-indicator-details/report-part-indicator-details.component';
import { ReportPartProblemareaDetailsComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-problemarea-details/report-part-problemarea-details.component';
import { ReportPartRolesDetailedComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-roles-details/report-part-roles-detailed.component';
import { CustomReportFilterItemComponent } from './components/CustomReport/custom-report-filter-item/custom-report-filter-item.component';
import {CustomReportCreatorComponent} from './components/CustomReport/custom-report-creator/custom-report-creator.component';
import {CustomReportFiltersComponent} from './components/CustomReport/custom-report-filters/custom-report-filters.component';
import { ReportPartSolutionCategoriesDetailsComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-solution-categories-details/report-part-solution-categories-details.component';
import { ReportPartSolutionCategoriesComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-solution-categories/report-part-solution-categories.component';
import { ReportPartStorylinesComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-storylines/report-part-storylines.component';
import { ReportPartRolesComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-roles/report-part-roles.component';
import { ReportPartStorylinesDetailedComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-storylines-detailed/report-part-storylines-detailed.component';
import { ReportPartDocumentsDetailedComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-documents-detailed/report-part-documents-detailed.component';
import {ReportPartMessagesDetailedComponent} from './components/ReportParts/report-part-messages-detailed/report-part-messages-detailed.component';
import { ReportPartDocumentsComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-documents/report-part-documents.component';
import {ReportPartMessagesComponent} from './components/ReportParts/report-part-messages/report-part-messages.component';
import { ReportPartStakeholdersComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-stakeholders/report-part-stakeholders.component';
import { ReportPartStakeholderOthersComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-stakeholder-others/report-part-stakeholder-others.component';
import { GameSelectionFilterComponent } from './components/shared/game-selection-filter/game-selection-filter.component';
import { DialogSaveCustomReportComponent } from './components/CustomReport/dialog-save-custom-report/dialog-save-custom-report.component';
import { ScenarioManagementFilterComponent } from './components/scenariomanagement/scenario-management-filter/scenario-management-filter.component';
import { ScenarioPartSolutionCategoryPipe } from './pipes/scenario-part-solution-category.pipe';
import { CompanyManagementComponent } from './components/companies/company-management/company-management.component';
import { DialogEditCompanyComponent } from './components/companies/dialog-edit-company/dialog-edit-company.component';
import { DialogEditDepartmentComponent } from './components/companies/dialog-edit-department/dialog-edit-department.component';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { GameAnalysesSelectionComponent } from './components/AAR/game-analyses-selection/game-analyses-selection.component';
import {SunMoonIndicatorComponent} from './components/gameplaysimulator/sun-moon-indicator/sun-moon-indicator.component';
import { LanguageSelectorComponent } from './components/shared/language-selector/language-selector.component';
import {ScenarioMainPageComponent} from './components/scenarioEdit/ScenarioMainPage/scenario-main-page.component';
import { CustomReportContentComponent } from './components/CustomReport/custom-report-content/custom-report-content.component';
import { CustomReportRouteContainerComponent } from './components/CustomReport/custom-report-route-container/custom-report-route-container.component';
import { ReportPartRolePlayerdescriptionComponent } from './components/ReportParts/report-part-role-playerdescription/report-part-role-playerdescription.component';

import { GenericDataGraphComponent } from './components/shared/generic-data-graph/generic-data-graph.component';
import { GameManagementComponent } from './components/managegames/game-management/game-management.component';
import { PropertyFilterPipe } from './pipes/property-filter.pipe';

registerLocaleData(localeNL, environment.DateFormatLocale);

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CrisisActionListComponent,
        WorkInProgressListComponent,
        IndicatorListComponent,
        CrisisDocumentListComponent,
        MessageListComponent,
        RealTimeIndicatorComponent,
        GameTimeIndicatorComponent,
        WorkInProgressItemComponent,
        CrisisActionComponent,
        IndicatorItemComponent,
        MessageItemComponent,
        CrisisDocumentComponent,
        DialogActionItemComponent,
        DialogMessageItemComponent,
        DialogInformationItemComponent,
        ProblemListComponent,
        ProblemItemComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        ContentViewerComponent,
        LoginPageComponent,
        LandingpageComponent,
        GameSelectionComponent,
        ScenarioMainPageComponent,
        ScenarioManagementComponent,
        ScenarioSubitemComponent,
        DialogEditBerichtItemComponent,
        FormErrorAlertComponent,
        WorkflowManagementComponent,
        TaskManagerComponent,
        TaskDetailsComponent,
        ScenarioTimelineComponent,
        WorkflowDetailsComponent,
        DialogEditWorkflowComponent,
        TaskDetailsListComponent,
        ScenarioDetailsComponent,
        DialogEditTaskComponent,
        TaskStatusPipe,
        DialogShowContentComponent,
        DialogEditActionComponent,
        OrderByPipe,
        DialogEditIndicatorComponent,
        DialogEditGameComponent,
        DialogEditGameParticipantsComponent,
        DialogGameInfoComponent,
        DialogEditActionRequiredDocumentsComponent,
        AfterActionDashboardComponent,
        DialogEditContentComponent,
        DialogEditDocumentComponent,
        DialogEditProblemareaComponent,
        DialogEditScenarioComponent,
        ScenarioPartDocumentPipe,
        ScenarioPartIndicatorPipe,
        ScenarioPartActionPipe,
        ScenarioPartWorkflowPipe,
        ScenarioPartMessagePipe,
        SubEditWorkflowInfoComponent,
        SubTriggerDescriptionComponent,
        ReportScenarioRouteComponent,
        ReportTimelineLogComponent,
        ReportScenarioPlayerReportComponent,
        ReportFullScenarioComponent,
        ScenarioWorkflowDetailsComponent,
        TriStateCheckboxComponent,
        ScenarioActionDetailsComponent,
        ReportDebriefingPreparationComponent,
        ScenarioPartStorylinePipe,
        DialogEditStorylineComponent,
        UserManagerComponent,
        UserDetailsComponent,
        DialogEditExecutorComponent,
        AbsolutePipe,
        VisualisationComponent,
        ScenarioStorylineEditorComponent,
        FilterStorylinePipe,
        UniqueStorylinesPipe,
        FilterStorylineFromWorkflowsPipe,
        ScenarioDocumentDetailsComponent,
        ScenarioIndicatorDetailsComponent,
        ScenarioProblemareaDetailsComponent,
        ScenarioExecutorDetailsComponent,
        StorylineManagementComponent,
        FilterActionFromStorylinePipe,
        DragDropWorkflowsComponent,
        DragDropActionsComponent,
        FilterStorylineFromWorkflowExtPipe,
        FilterActionsExtendedFromStorylinePipe,
        DialogEditRoleComponent,
        ScenarioPartRolePipe,
        GenericInformationalPopupComponent,
        ReportScenarioRolesComponent,
        SafeHtmlPipe,
        ReportGameplayContentComponent,
        ScenarioRoleDetailsComponent,
        DateTimeSelectorComponent,
        DateTimeSelectorComponent,
        BulkCreateUsersComponent,
        BulkEditUsersComponent,
        ScenarioPartProblemareaPipe,
        ScenarioMessageDetailsComponent,
        FilterWorkflowFromSolutionCatPipe,
        FilterActionFromSolutionCatPipe,
        ScenarioSolutionCategoriesDetailsComponent,
        DialogEditSolutionCategoryComponent,
        StakeholderReportComponent,
        ReportUserExecutedActionsComponent,
        DialogSelectScenarioComponent,
        CustomReportCreatorComponent,
        CustomReportFiltersComponent,
        ReportPartIndicatorsComponent,
        ReportPartProblemareasComponent,
        ReportPartIndicatorDetailsComponent,
        ReportPartProblemareaDetailsComponent,
        ReportPartRolesDetailedComponent,
        CustomReportFilterItemComponent,
        ReportPartSolutionCategoriesDetailsComponent,
        ReportPartSolutionCategoriesComponent,
        ReportPartStorylinesComponent,
        ReportPartRolesComponent,
        ReportPartStorylinesDetailedComponent,
        ReportPartDocumentsDetailedComponent,
        ReportPartMessagesDetailedComponent,
        ReportPartMessagesComponent,
        ReportPartDocumentsComponent,
        ReportPartStakeholdersComponent,
        ReportPartStakeholderOthersComponent,
        GameSelectionFilterComponent,
        DialogSaveCustomReportComponent,
        ScenarioManagementFilterComponent,
        ScenarioPartSolutionCategoryPipe,
        CompanyManagementComponent,
        DialogEditCompanyComponent,
        DialogEditDepartmentComponent,
        GameAnalysesSelectionComponent,
        SunMoonIndicatorComponent,
        LanguageSelectorComponent,
        CustomReportContentComponent,
        CustomReportRouteContainerComponent,
        ReportPartRolePlayerdescriptionComponent,
        GenericDataGraphComponent,
        GameManagementComponent,
        PropertyFilterPipe,
    ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    GaugeChartModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatListModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
    DragDropModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    HammerModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTreeModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatRippleModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogEditBerichtItemComponent,
    DialogEditWorkflowComponent,
    DialogEditTaskComponent,
    DialogEditIndicatorComponent,
    DialogEditActionComponent,
    DialogShowContentComponent,
    DialogEditGameComponent,
    DialogEditActionRequiredDocumentsComponent,
    DialogEditProblemareaComponent,
    DialogEditScenarioComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    httpInterceptorProviders,
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
      useValue: {
        parse: {
          dateInput: ['YYYY-MM-DD', 'YYYY-MM-DD'],
        },
        display: {
          dateInput: 'dddd DD MMMM YYYY',
          monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
          dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
          monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    ServiceLocator.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is this component declared? Is it declared in the same module where you already imported mat-grid-list?

Comment: Yes, the project is one angular Module. So it is declared in the app.module.ts. I am thinking to split it up in several modules, but didn't get to change that yet

Comment: Can you share your full app.module or lazy loaded module if you have ofc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing WorkflowTriggersManagerComponent from declarations in app.module.ts.

Please add it in app.module.ts

```
   Declarations: [
    WorkflowTriggersManagerComponent, ...]
```

Comment: Also thanks to @Tu Nguyen. I cannot believe how I missed this. (banging had on desk). Somehow this must have gone lost in GIT-merges or something, because "it worked last week". We've all been there I guess. Many, Many thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Pianoman it happens and you are mostly welcome. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Is the component that's showing the error included in the same module that is importing `MatGridListModule`? This is pretty much the only way for this error to be showing up.

Comment: Will look at it ASAP!